# Why is codeception running middleware on routes in Laravel which should not be run?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, codeception, laravel-middleware

So I am a codeception newbie and I am trying to figure out how to test my web service using the same. I have written my first simple test for the `authenticate` route just to make sure that the application is spitting out the JWT token like it should. The test looks like so:

```
<?php 
$I = new ApiTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('authenticate a user');
$I->haveHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
$I->sendPOST('/api/authenticate', [
    'username' => 'archive',
    'email' => 'admin@admin.com',
    'password' => 'password'
]);
$I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
$I->seeResponseIsJson();
```

In my defense I have tried the same POST from Postman and it works perfectly.

**api.suite.yml**

```
class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - REST:
            url: http://localhost:8000/api/
            depends: Laravel5
    config: 
        Laravel5:
            environment_file: .env.testing
```

The problem that I am facing in this test is that it does not see the `200 OK` as the response code but sees `500` instead. Later I realized I can go through the outputs of the same in the `_output` directory and I saw this error:

> The token could not be parsed from the request

Now to my surprise, the `authenticate` route should not even require a token so I went on to look where in my application is the token being parsed. Finally I realized that there is a middleware called `ChangeDb` which is in the `Kernal` and it looks to check the token from every request except the `authenticate` route. It looks like so:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if($request->path() != 'api/authenticate'){
        $username = \JWTAuth::parseToken()->getPayload()->get('username');

        if(! $username){
            \Config::set('database.connections.tenant.database', 'archive');
            \DB::reconnect();
            \DB::setDatabaseName('archive');
        }else{
            \Config::set('database.connections.tenant.database', $username); 
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

But when I tried to comment this out of the Kernal, the test runs fine and gives me green. So somehow this middleware runs fine when I try it from Postman and other ajax request, but when Codeception tries the request, the `if statement` returns `true` apparently because it looks at the token and this is where my test fails.

So why is this happening? Does the request generated from Codeception is different somehow from the request generated from Postman or my ajax application on the front end? How to work around this?

Comment: add `var_dump($request->path()); die;` to beginning of the handle method and re-run this test. What output do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I assumed `Laravel5` as the dependency in the REST section was the issue. It was not simulating real `HTTP` requests and which is why the `middleware` could not tell where the request was coming from. I changed it to  `PhpBrowser` and it works now. `PhpBrowser` apparently simulates real `HTTP` requests.